# How can I hide or show some text fields on checkbox click in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, forms, checkbox, woocommerce

I have some text field i.e in custom size(length,with) of product.
I want include a check box , when i click on check box , custom size fields will show/hide on checkbox click.please help me how i can perform this without any code customization.

I had tried some plugins but they add text fields but not show/hide them on checkbox click [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add some scripts to make the code work. That is, you need to capture the checkbox click and analysing checked is true or false, you have to write code to show or hide the fields. A simple jQuery function is sufficient.

Or you can use product option plugins to make it work. I don't know which plugin you have used. I have used this one for my client. Try [this](https://www.themehigh.com/product/woocommerce-extra-product-options) if you need a plugin.

Comment: Sir please confirm that is it paid plugin? And please guide me which condition/rule will perform show and hide of form fields?

Comment: Yeah. it's a paid plugin. I have used that plugin to show some select fields based on check box. So you can toggle between show and hide fields on clicking checkbox. They have a demo site available. So check the demo and make sure the plugins meet your requirements

Comment: They do have a free version. i don't know if free version has conditional rules. Better check the link in my answer and contact them